# Phonegap application crashes with memory warning

Tags: javascript, ipad, cordova

We have a Phonegap appliction in iOS which has a very high data which is downloaded form the server. The Phonegap version used is 2.9.0. At a certain point, the application works fine. But as the amount of data increases the application crashes giving memory warning error. We are using HTML and Javascript to bind the data with the elements. But we have not yet found the reason for the crash.

We have the following code in AppDelegate's init method

```
    - (id)init
{
    /** If you need to do any extra app-specific initialization, you can do it here
     *  -jm
     **/
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    [cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

    int cacheSizeMemory = 8 * 1024 * 1024; // 8MB
    int cacheSizeDisk = 32 * 1024 * 1024; // 32MB

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad || [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        cacheSizeMemory *= 20;
        cacheSizeDisk *= 20;
    }

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        NSURLCache* sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
#else
        NSURLCache* sharedCache = [[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"] autorelease];
#endif
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

    self = [super init];
    return self;
}
```

Also we have added the below code in the applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

The above things have not helped us yet. Any kind of help and guidance is most appreciated.